# Array object[] in covariance behavior

Tags: c#, covariance

[I had a compile error while assinging `int[]` to `object[]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7300780/c-sharp-compiler-error-while-assigning-int-to-object) (the question is not mine).

The accepted answer states that that's because the array covariance (please read the question and the answer for the sake of better understanding).

Now my situation is that while I cannot assign `int[]` to `object[]` because `int` is value type (`struct`) I wonder why I can do this now:

```
var arrayOfObjects = new object[] { 58, 58, 78 };// it accepts values types as initializers!
```

Why does this work if I am initializing value types to the array object? Should not be reciprocal not accepting values types neither?

Comment: This is called [boxing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx). The `int` values are being converted from a value type to an object.

Comment: Arrays have nothing to do with covariance.

Comment: I don't see where youre using covariance in your code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you're (implicitly) casting one item after another into `object`. You're not assigning a `int[]` array to a `object[]` variable - you're creating an `object[]` variable from individual `int` values (which get implicitly cast and boxed).

To show this without the array initializer:

```
object[] objarr = new object[1];
objarr[0] = 42; // Fine, translates basically into objarr[0] = (object)42;

int[] intarr = new int[1];
intarr[0] = 42; // Also fine

objarr = intarr; // No can do!
```

Comment: So, if I initialize the array with a decimal value(5.2), will the entire value be preserved with the boxing thing? Or will it change(lets say to 5)?

Comment: @Misters It will be preserved. The `decimal` will get boxed, there won't be any implicit conversions.

Answer (score 2):

Here you are not building an `int[]`, the integers are being boxed into objects and you're building an `object[]` instead. You could box other things too:

```
var arrayOfObjects = new object[] { true, "false", 1, 10, new StringBuilder() }
```

Answer (score 1):

To complete the point of view from the compilers perspective, given the following statement:

```
void Main()
{
    object[] or = new object[] { 1, 2 };
}
```

This is the IL emitted by the compiler:

```
IL_0001:  ldc.i4.2    
IL_0002:  newarr      System.Object
IL_0007:  stloc.1     // System.Object[]
IL_0008:  ldloc.1     // System.Object[]
IL_0009:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_000A:  ldc.i4.1    
IL_000B:  box         System.Int32
IL_0010:  stelem.ref  
IL_0011:  ldloc.1     // System.Object[]
IL_0012:  ldc.i4.1    
IL_0013:  ldc.i4.2    
IL_0014:  box         System.Int32
IL_0019:  stelem.ref  
IL_001A:  ldloc.1     // System.Object[]
IL_001B:  stloc.0     // or
IL_001C:  ret
```

The compiler takes the values, does a `box` operation of the value type (`int`) and then calls `stelem.ref`, which replaces the value of the element at the supplied index in the one-dimensional array with the ref (type O) value pushed onto the stack.